# Macbook Pro - Cmd tab and cmd space stop working

Tags: mac, macos

The <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> (to alternate between applications) and <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>Space</kbd>   (for Spotlight) stop working on my Mac once I open the GNS3 application (GNS3 is a virtual network simulator that I use for my Cisco studies).

I did look at GNS3 support, actually looked at their forums. No one else as yet has faced this issue. I haven't upgraded to the new version of GNS3 and haven't made any changes at all on my Mac. I've been using the same version for over a year now and haven't faced this issue. This just randomly started yesterday.

If I logout and login again, the problem seems to resolve. However, once I start GNS3 again, the problem may or may not persist.

It's just random. Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening all of a sudden?

Comment: Two questions:  1)  What is GNS3 and 2) if the problem exists only in GNS3 have you looked at their support?

Comment: Allan, thanks for responding.

GNS3 is a virtual network simulator that I use for my Cisco studies. I also use iTerm along with GNS3 to access the CLI of the virtual devices running on the GNS3 VM. 

I did look at GNS3 support, actually looked at their forums. No one else as yet has faced this issue. I haven't upgraded to the new version of GNS3 and haven't made any changes at all on my MAC. I've been using the same version for over a year now and haven't faced this issue.   This just randomly started yesterday.

Comment: Did you look at the keyboard shortcuts to see if the app is using them for some reason?

Comment: I've confirmed and there seems to be no overlaps.